# unable to extract the group under gitlab through API call

Tags: bash, api, curl, jq

I am using shell script to list out all the group under GITLAB. its huge number of list how can we find out all groups, its more than 30 seems. and iterate through it to find out ID of group?
if any other solution please suggest to list all the group ID.

```
grouplist=$(curl --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: $1" "https://gitlab.com/api/v4/groups?per_page=100&page=30" | jq -r '.[].id')
```

Comment: Use a shell loop and iterate all the pages?

Answer (score 1):

The gitlab documentation says:

> When accessed without authentication, this endpoint also supports keyset pagination:

> When requesting consecutive pages of results, we recommend you use keyset pagination.
> Beyond a specific offset limit (specified by max offset allowed by the REST API for offset-based pagination), offset pagination is unavailable.

See https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/index.html#keyset-based-pagination for more details about keyset pagination.  You will have to call curl repeatedly until there are no more results:

> When the end of the collection is reached and there are no additional records to retrieve, the Link header is absent and the resulting array is empty. We recommend using only the given link to retrieve the next page instead of building your own URL.

The retrieved JSON documents can then can be fed to jq.